# What is the right way to pass a value from the UI to another thread?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have the `MainActivity` thread which contains a `Fragment` class. The purpose of that fragment is to allow user to connect to a `Bluetooth` device.

After the user is connected the `ConnectedThread` starts its while loop which is listening to incoming bytes.

In the `MainActivity` I have a `Boolean` value which changes based on whether checkbox is checked or not. I would like to pass that value from the `MainActivity` to that while loop when it changes.

So the question is, what is the right way to do that? Is there any trick like a handler for that? Or should I pass the context to the `ConnectedThread` and then set a listener for that in the `ConnectedThread` class?

Comment: maybe you should use BroadCast
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use interface as callback here. declare an `interface` in your `MainActivity` and have your class with connected thread implement it.

once value changes in `MainActivity` trigger the callback method and you can pass your variable as a parameter to other class.

Comment: Thank you Rahul, I was just wondering, why is this better solution than passing the context and setting the listener on the Connectedthread? I am pretty sure it is better, but why?

Comment: well I can not tell definitely whether it's better or not performance wise but this way your classes will be decoupled and will not have multiple reasons to change. in sort more aligned to OOP.

Comment: I see, good point. Anyway I am thinking about how to implement it. If I have no direct connection between MainActivity and the ConnectedThread class, how can I declare it in the MainActivity?

Comment: that's the point, there need not to be a connection. MainActivity is owner of the variable and will be publishing it to anyone who asks.

Comment: I get it, thanks a lot for your educational time! Amazing job :).

Comment: would you come on skype? I can offer you something in return. Please. Mine is: zatokar1

Comment: we can chat [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91958/room-for-rahul-tiwari-and-ondrej-tokar)